# Receive sensor values from bluetooth hc05 to Android

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, arduino

I'm sending sensor values from Arduino via an HC-05 Bluetooth module to Android. I'm receiving the values but they are not showing properly in my textviews.

I'm using 2 sensors and their values are like this (example first sensor = 120, 97, 110 etc)

Sensor2 values are like this (97, 96, 100 etc)
i.e values are changing.

Now my Android code is:

```
if (msg.what == handlerState) {
  //if message is what we want
  String readMessage = (String) msg.obj;
  // msg.arg1 = bytes from connect thread
  recDataString.append(readMessage);
  //keep appending to string until ~
  int endOfLineIndex = recDataString.indexOf("~");
  // determine the end-of-line
  if (endOfLineIndex > 0) {
    // make sure there data before ~
    String dataInPrint = recDataString.substring(0, endOfLineIndex);
    // extract string
    if (recDataString.charAt(0) == '#') {
      //if it starts with # we know it is what we are looking for
      String sensor0 = recDataString.substring(1, 3);
      //get sensor value from string between indices 1-5
      String sensor1 = recDataString.substring(4, 6);
      //same again...
      heart_rate.setText(sensor0);
      // update the textviews with sensor values
      temperature.setText(sensor1);
    }
    recDataString.delete(0, recDataString.length());
    //clear all string data
    dataInPrint = " ";
  }
}
```

When I receive 2-digit data on sensor 1 like this (76) and 2-digit data also on sensor 2 (97) it shows the data properly. But if values are greater than 3 digits the values don't show up properly and some digits of the first textview appear on the second textview. I think the problem is getting the data between the indices. How can I manage this? Please help me.

Sorry for my bad English, I'm not a native speaker.

Comment: Still no response